# A low-rep user approved my edit. How is this possible?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, review, suggested-edits

I just made an edit to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1319791/145141) post and found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/429753) that the OP, a user with not nearly 2k reputation (704 at the moment), has approved my suggested edit.

How can this be? Is it because he's the OP? I've certainly never noticed  that I can review suggested edits to my own posts. (And if I can, then I would like to know how/where to do so.) Or is something being displayed incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, because he's the OP. You can review suggested edits to your own posts when you are quick enough to get to it before others approve or reject it. You get an inbox notification of suggested edits on your own post. The OP's vote is binding, so the OP can single-handedly approve or reject a suggestion.

Comment: I'm tempted to call this a duplicate of [How the user with reputation <100 may get the “Custodian” badge?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10522/how-the-user-with-reputation-100-may-get-the-custodian-badge).

Comment: @ArthurFischer Resistance is futile. Give in to the temptation ;)

Comment: See also: [Today and yesterday I noticed new users who were able to access suggested edit reviews](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19379/today-and-yesterday-i-noticed-new-users-who-were-able-to-access-suggested-edit-r)

Comment: To answer the part: *If I can review suggested edits to my own post then where/how?* According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133550/183484) you should receive notification if your post received a suggested edit with a link to suggested edit - using that link you should be able to review the edit. (At least if I understood that post correctly and if this process have not changed  significantly in the meantime.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, because he's the OP. You can review suggested edits to your own posts when you are quick enough to get to it before others approve or reject it. According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133550/183484) you get an inbox notification of suggested edits on your own post. The OP's vote is binding, so the OP can single-handedly approve or reject a suggestion.