# Appealing a rejected edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I recently edited an answer to a question in differential geometry about computing the round metric.

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1575851

The provided answer was a correct approach, however, there is a clear typo that will confuse viewers of the answer by replacing $\theta$ with $\psi$ in the denominator of a partial derivative.

One reviewer approved it but two did not, saying it makes the answer more confusing. Clearly, they didn't even look closely at the answer or the edit.

What are my course of actions here?

Can I resubmit the edit or appeal the decision?

Comment: As a side note, the OP has the final say about any suggested edit. So they could still override the decision of the reviewers, if they disagree with them. (See, for example, [A low-rep user approved my edit. How is this possible?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20735) or the FAQ post: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)) Have you considered leaving a comment under the post. (The OP can then make the correction themselves or they might approve your suggested edit.)

Comment: Seems like a good edit to me. $\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial \phi}\cdot\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial \phi}$ can't be $0$ and $\sin^2(\theta)$ for every $\theta$.

Comment: I think the best course of action is to leave a comment below the answer asking for the typo to be corrected, as Martin suggested.

Comment: I will leave a comment as suggested. Thanks for the advice.